# detect self intersecting polyline in wpf

Tags: wpf, intersection, polyline

I am trying to write a method to determine whether a polyline is self-intersecting or not. I found some similar answers already in this site, but none matched with my condition. Here my polyline is dynamically created with some logics.

Is there any wpf inbuilt function to do this? If not then what could be the logic to do this?